# Spark Shell stuck in YARN Accepted state

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

Running Spark 1.3.1 on Yarn and EMR.  When I run the spark-shell everything looks normal until I start seeing messages like `INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1439330624449_1561 (state: ACCEPTED)`.  These messages are generated endlessly, once per second.  Meanwhile, I am unable to use the Spark shell.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: did you add the -x argument when you did Add Application for Spark (during the amazon cluster config?) Also are you manually configuring the cluster or using a script to provision the AWS cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realized there were a couple of streaming jobs I had killed in the terminal, but I guess they were somehow still running. I was able to find these in the UI showing all running applications on YARN (I wasn't able to execute Hive queries as either). Once I killed the jobs using the command below the spark-shell started as usual.

```
yarn application -kill application_1428487296152_25597
```

Answer (score 9):

Seeing (near) endless Accepted messages from YARN has always been a sure sign that there were not enough cluster resources to allocate for my Spark jobs / shell. YARN will continue trying to schedule your Spark application, but will eventually time-out if not enough resources become available in a certain amount of time.

Are you providing any command line options to spark-shell that override the defaults provided? When I ask for too many executors/cores/memory YARN will accept my request but never transition to a Running ApplicationMaster.

Try running a spark-shell with no options (other than perhaps --master yarn) and see if it gets past Accepted.

Comment: Actually just running `spark-shell` without any command line options

Comment: @DJElbow what machine instances are you using so we can see the hardware specs?

Comment: Realized there were a couple of streaming jobs I had killed in the terminal, but I guess they were somehow still running.  I was able to find these in the UI showing all running applications on YARN.  I wasn't able to execute Hive queries as well.  Once I killed the jobs using `yarn application -kill application_1428487296152_25597` the spark-shell started as usual.

Comment: @DJElbow Glad you figured it out! Seeing endless Accepted messages from YARN has always been a sure sign that there were not enough cluster resources to allocate whatever work Spark job I requested.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that YARN is not having resources enough for running jobs.

Please check 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html
for calculating how many resources can you provide to YARN.

Please check the number of cores and the RAM quantity that it is controlled by the following variables:

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb

Comment: If you put those conf with `spark-submit`, remember to put `spark.` before each command. For example, the first would become `spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores` and the second `spark.yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`