# pyspark hanging after logging "INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Running pyspark to join two dataframes and having problem where pyspark hangs after outputting logs...

> INFO FileSourceScanExec: Planning scan with bin packing, max size: 25933503 bytes, open cost is considered as scanning 4194304 bytes.
>
> ...
>
> INFO DAGScheduler: looking for newly runnable stages
>
> INFO DAGScheduler: running: Set(ShuffleMapStage 6)
>
> pyspark hanging INFO DAGScheduler: failed: Set()

Hangs for long time.

Relevant code snippet...

```py
other_table = sparksession.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle.domain.local:12345/DBNAME")\
        .option("user", DB_CREDS["oracle"]["username"])\
        .option("password", DB_CREDS["oracle"]["password"])\
        .option("dbtable", f"({PK_SELECTION_QUERY})") \
        .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
        .load()
    other_table = other_table.dropDuplicates()

    print("\n\nfilter table:")
    other_table.show(n=3)

    orig_order = df.columns  # in case PK joining changes original column positions
    df = df.join(other_table.select("TX_ID"), "TX_ID", "leftsemi").select(orig_order)
    df.show(n=5)
```

with configs...

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC" 
--conf "spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1" 
--jars /home/airflow/tmp/ojdbc6.jar
```

Not sure what more info I can add to this post to give more helpful information.

Anyone with more experience with pyspark know what could be happening here? Any more debugging hints or info that could be provided to make post more helpful?

Comment: I do not know how you have deployed spark. But do you have more logs or information from a Spark History ? Does the Spark Framework create driver and executors ?

Comment: I don't see a join in the code snippet. Do you already get the error before the join? Does it already occur at the `.show` step?

Comment: @Paul Oops forgot to add that, edited.

Comment: @airliquide Pretty new to spark underlying stuff (FYI have spark deployed on an HDP cluster), but after more debugging I think I understand how to read / interpret the spark logging information a bit better now. Currently suspect the problem is this (https://stackoverflow.com/q/32658840/8236733), but need to test more (have since changed the code to try other solutions). Will update when have more info...